# Постоянное отображение Content-Assist для Android в Eclipse, как?

Tags: android, eclipse

Заинтересовался разработкой под Android. Поставил Eclipse, Android SDK, до этого писал на C# WPF. Сразу встал вопрос: как в Eclipse сделать, чтобы Content-Assist постоянно был активен, а не только при нажатии Ctrl+Space? Поначалу и не знаешь всех методов и свойств, подсказка лишней бы не была, а тут постоянно приходится ее вызывать.

p.s. Привык, что в Visual Studio подсказки всегда видны...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ну и никто не отменял idea - для андроида есть бесплатная версия.

...которая сейчас мало чем уступает Eclipse с ADT, не то что раньше! графическое превью отлично работает. Так что автору вопроса думается именно Idea 12 Community Edition и нужна. Те кто видел у меня открытой спрашивали "Это студия?" :) хотя лучше обе сразу юзать, удобно

Ну а если так хочется Eclipse, то на почитать:

- [Mastering Eclipse Content Assist for Android](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/mastering-eclipse-content-assist-for-android.html);
- [Tips and Tricks (JDT)](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html);
- [How to make Eclipse's content assist behavior similar to Visual Studio's IntelliSence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278093/how-to-make-eclipses-content-assist-behavior-similar-to-visual-studios-intelli).

Comment: последняя ссылка оказалось наиболее информативной, спасибо.

Оказывается, нужно было просто в триггеры вызова асиста (search: Auto activation triggers for Java) добавить буквы и другие символы, тогда будет выводить подсказку всегда.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию он показывается через 0.2 секунды, если нажали точку. А показывать абсолютно постоянно - не вижу смысла.

Но возможно у Вас он просто отключен? Тогда используя меню "окно->параметры" (в руссокой локализации) открываем окно настроек. Настроек там много, поэтому пользуемся фильтром (поле ввода вверху слева), куда пишем "Auto activation". На появившейся вкладке можно поднастроить.

Ну и никто не отменял idea - для андроида есть бесплатная версия.

Comment: спасибо, попробую Idea, т.к. выставил в 0 задержку, а показывает все равно при нажатии

Comment: попробовал Idea: с наскока разобраться , как с Eclipse не удалось, потому решил остаться с Eclipse.